# Inheritance in combination with class Attribute parameters and insertions into ViewData

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, design-patterns

Question is for educational purposes only.

I have MVC application that has 3 Web Journeys that mirror one another in many ways - which makes it convenient to introduce Base class that would take care of common parts.

I am also using lots of class attributes that are being put into `viewData` 
this makes it convenient when reusing the views between journeys where I can insert different phone number (or other bits) per journey without need to inherit this data in each viewModel, as it is same per journey (not placeable into master page as it is shown in many different views). These constants also are used in code when generating emails and such.

```
[LayoutViewData(ContactNumber = ContactNumber, LegalType = LegalType, LegalReference = LegalReference)]
public class JourneyController : BaseJourneyController
{
    private const string ContactNumber = "0800 161 5191";
    private const string ContactNumberForPricingPage = "0800 051 3322";
    private const string ProductReference = "LS0083";
    private const string LegalReference = "conveyancing";
}


public class LayoutViewDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Add("ContactNumber", this.ContactNumber);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Problem that I am trying to solve:**

There are methods that are almost identical in journeys and could be moved to base but they require values from constants. Problem is that only statics can be passed into attributes, which means I cannot simply change them to abstract properties with getters only and move on with my life.

**My options:**

1. Change method signatures to pass these constants into method - I don't like this since having to pass data to base indicates that implementation should be in class itself.
2. Introduce abstract Get methods that would then return constants for use in base class eg.

   ```
   protected override string GetContactNumber()
   {
       return ContactNumber;
   }
   ```

   I don't like that there is no way to force to return those specific constants and feels a bit hacky, yet IMHO best solution for least amount of effort.
3. Get rid of constants and attributes and introduce BaseViewModel class that would have abstract properties and one mechanism per journey that would set there values. Or could be 3 base classes with those properties already set. - don't like it, lots of replacements.

**Can you think of some other solution that would be minimum work and minimum hacks that would solve my situation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main issue here is that you are using Attributes for a purpose they are not intended for. Attributes are for adding meta-data to a code construct. But you are using them to attach *data* that should normally be part of the actual object definition (as property getters).

In addition, I don't believe you necessarily have to resort to class inheritance to come up with a design that will work for this case. But if you need to, this solution will still work.

## Separate Interfaces

If you break each piece of data into its own interface, you can take advantage of the fact that a class can implement multiple interfaces to override the default values as needed.

```
public interface IContactNumber
{
    string ContactNumber { get; }
}
```

## Separate Action Fitlers

Rather than inheriting `ActionFilterAttribute` which comes with its own built-in limitations, you could just implement `IActionFilter` to cut the unnecessary Attribute from the equation.

```
public class ContactNumberActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string defaultContactNumber;

    public ContactNumberActionFilter(string defaultContactNumber)
    {
        this.defaultContactNumber = defaultContactNumber;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // No implementation
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.Controller;
        var provider = controller as IContactNumber;
        var contactNumber = (provider == null) ? this.defaultContactNumber : provider.ContactNumber;

        controller.ViewData.Add("ContactNumber", contactNumber);
    }
}
```

Then it is just a matter of registering your filter globally.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        // Register the action filter globally and provide a default number
        filters.Add(new ContactNumberActionFilter("0800 161 5191"));

        // TODO: Make filters for ContactNumberForPricingPage, 
        // ProductReference, and LegalReference and set their default
        // values here.
    }
}
```

## Usage

Now, if you want to override the default contact number, you simply need to implement `IContactNumber` in your controller. If you don't implement this interface, the default number will be used.

```
public class HomeController : Controller, IContactNumber
{
    public string ContactNumber
    {
        get { return "0800 161 5192"; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Note that you *could* also add a way to turn this feature on or off by using an Attribute and testing for its presence before adding the `ContactNumber` to the `ViewData` if you really need an on/off switch.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ContactNumberAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: I love your solution. I really didn't like the pile of constants at the top of each controller especially not being forced by interface, but having every VM inherit from some BaseVM just to get in some obscure places bits of data seemed even worse. This solution is much more elegant - hats down.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're trying to use the Template Pattern.

If I was approaching this pattern I'd use an interface to define the contract for providing the "constants":

```
public interface IJourneyConstants
{ 
     string ContactNumber {get;}
     string ContactNumberForPricingPage{ get;}
     string ProductReference {get;}
     string LegalReference = {get;}
}
```

Then you would define your class(es) that would provide such data:

```
public class ExampleJourneyConstantProvider : IJourneyConstants
{
   string IJourneyConstants.ContactNumber => "0800 161 5191";
   string IJourneyConstants.ContactNumberForPricingPage => "0800 051 3322";
   string IJourneyConstants.ProductReference => "LS0083";
   string IJourneyConstants.LegalReference => "conveyancing";
}
```

I used explicit interface implementation in this example.  It's not necessary, but if you put this in a `Controller` it makes you're Controller look a bit cleaner.

Then you'd define a `Controller`:

```
 [LayoutViewData(Provider = typeof(ExampleJourneyConstantProvider)]
 public class ExampleJourneyController : Controller{
 }
```

Note:  There's no reason you're controller couldn't implement `IJourneyConstants`:

```
 [LayoutViewData(Provider = typeof(ExampleJourneyController )]
 public class ExampleJourneyController : Controller, IJourneyConstants{
 }
```

You're `ActionFilter` would then dynamically create an instance of the Provider**, cast it, apply any common Tempting Engine code and update the ViewData:

```
 public class LayoutViewDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        IJourneyConstants constants;

         try{
           constants = (IJourneyConstants )System.Activator.CreateInstance(this.Provider);
         }catch (Exception e){
             throw new Exception("Failed to create instance of IJourneyConstants from " + 
                 $"{this.Provider.Name}.  Ensure it inherits from IJourneyConstants "+ 
                  "and contains a public paramaterless constructor.");
         }

         // perform any common calculation using your constants
         bool isContactNumberInternational = constants.ContactNumber.StartsWith("+");

         // update the ViewData
         filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Add("ContactNumber", 
             constants.ContactNumber);
         filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Add("IsNumberInternational", 
             isContactNumberInternational);
   }    
}
```